# Is wordpress written in MVC pattern?

Tags: mvc

Is WordPress written in MVC architect?

How to understand a CMS is a MVC?

A CMS that written in MVC must have directories with named "Model", "Controller", "View"?

Sorry for my beginner question .

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress dosen't follow MVC (Model-View-Controller) nor is written with OOP approach in mind. Anyway you can write your plugins with a MVC pattern or using OOP. One excelent tool to use MVC in Wordpress is [WP MVC](http://wpmvc.org/)

Answer (score 2):

No, Wordpress is not MVC Architecture.

An application that is written in MVC, most of the time recognise by their directory structure:

> - Models
> - Controllers
> - Views
> - Application (Optional)